# How to start gitlab?

Tags: linux, gitlab

I used command `service gitlab start` to start gitlab, but it failed.

The error message:

> "Failed to start gitlab-ctrl.service: Unit not found".

I really don't know how to do it, Who know how to start gitlab. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you have made your configurations in your `gitlab.rb`(presuming you used the omnibus installation) and you did `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, you can start it with `sudo gitlab-ctl start`.

Check the documentation on `gitlab-ctl` [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/maintenance/README.html#starting-and-stopping).

Answer (score 2):

More info on your question here: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1604

also do a reconfigure before start `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
And try to do `sudo systemctl start gitlab-ctl`